# flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 - build appbundle failing, but actually producing an appbundle

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Since upgrading flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.2 to, when I run `flutter build appbundle`, flutter finishes  with an error:

```
Initializing gradle...                                              0,9s
Resolving dependencies...                                           3,6s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       114,5s
Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.
```

But actually it did Produce a valid appbundle, `flutter build appbundle -v` finishes with:

```
[   +2 ms] 161 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 156 up-to-date
[ +361 ms] Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (completed in 75,1s)
[   +7 ms] "flutter appbundle" took 80.137ms.
Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      _buildGradleProjectV2 (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:780:7)
#2      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
#9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:30:15)
#10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:288:13)
```

It looks like gradle crashes after finishing the appbundle. Anyone have the same Problem or any Ideas?

My Flutter doctor: 
Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at C:\src\flutter
     • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (8 days ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
     • Engine revision b863200c37
     • Dart version 2.5.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
 version 29.0.2)
     • Android SDK at C:\Users\dirkb\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
     • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
     • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
     • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
     • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
     • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
     • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
     • Dart plugin version 191.8423
     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

Comment: Finally I found the problem, but still no solution. 

flutter appbundle creates \build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab but gradle expects \build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app.aab

This is a known bug and supposed to be fixed already, but as of flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.5 this still is there. [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38934](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38934)

When you build the appbundle, rename it to app.aab and run the same build again, gradle finishes without error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not weird, it is a bug. gradle displays an error message even if everything went well.

**SOLUTION**

Edit your `build.gradle` and change

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'`

to:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

**DETAILS**

I encountered two bugs with *tools.build:gradle:3.5.0*:

First of all, `local.properties` is re-build every time you compile, (don't it check-in!)

a) with *gradle*, using `flutter build appbundle --release -v` the result is `sdk.dir=C:\\....\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk` (no matter which tool version)

b) with *IntelliJ* is was `sdk.dir=C:/..../AppData/Local/Android/Sdk`

Unfortunately, `tools.build:gradle:3.5.0` fail when reading the path they create, where `tools.build:gradle:3.4.2` work.

I you want to use tools v3.5.0 do this:

`set ANDROID_HOME=C:/Users/msc/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk`
(slash, not backslash, on Windows!!)

After that, *gradle* did the build and finished with 
*Gradle build failed to produce an Android bundle package.*
which is weird because *gradle* actually did the full job. The file is there: `\build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab`.

So, error message without error?

Obviously gradle.tools v3.5.0 have problems with path names, at least on Windows.

And... just another tip: check your `android\key.properties` file and make sure the `storeFile=` setting is correct.

`key.properties storeFile=c:/pathToMyKeyStore.jks`

**NOTE: You should use / in the path, not \**

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem as well. You can't create an app bundle in flutter at the moment, there is a bug with the file naming when the aab is created. Just use Android Studio to create the aab file.

```
Build > Build APK/Bundle > Build Bundle(s)
```

Edit: Bonus, not asked but might be helpful to know if anyone doesn't already know. I had some users unable to use my app. Add the following to your gradle file to ensure the app bundle includes the following libraries.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        //add the following
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funny, for me in Android Studio the Build Bundle is grayed out, but `flutter build appbundle` creates a perfectly fine aab file, despite the error message. It uploaded to Google Play and I didn't hear of any problems so far.

Comment: @dirkbo, very peculiar. What channel are you on? I normally develop on dev but recently changed to beta for my releases.

Comment: I'm on stable actually... I tried some `flutter clean`, but still remains... At least the aab builds ok, so i can live with it, but... it's weird...

Answer (score 0):

On the path to setting is android/app/build.gradle:

try this one:
minifyEnabled false

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and this is what I did:

1.Deleted ".idea" folder and "build" folder as well as "pubspec-lock" file.
2.Then run flutter pub get in my console

It Should Work