# Flutter - Appbundle - Android app freezes on start

Tags: android, flutter

I have an app with more than 150k+ users and I have avoided using appbundle until now just because I don't know how it really works, but last week I had no choice and sent an update with an appbundle. Since then, many users are reporting that the app is **freezing on start with a black screen** (It has no splash screen).

I took a look on the *Android Vitals* in the *Play Console* and I found this

> signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

```
backtrace:

  #00  pc 000000000014d960  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #01  pc 0000000000140bcb  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #02  pc 000000000014389d  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #03  pc 0000000000010255  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+576)

  #04  pc 000000000000ff7d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+32)

  #05  pc 000000000000c543  /system/lib/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+50)

  #06  pc 0000000000143979  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #07  pc 0000000000140a5b  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #08  pc 00000000001429cd  /data/app/my.app-aw5yMuTEkO-Q1NwkE1kbgg==/lib/arm/libflutter.so

  #09  pc 0000000000048811  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+24)

  #10  pc 000000000001b369  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)


backtrace:

  #00  pc 0000000000714094  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #01  pc 000000000028c314  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #02  pc 000000000027d698  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #03  pc 000000000028105c  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #04  pc 000000000001c004  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+524)

  #05  pc 000000000001c268  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+80)

  #06  pc 000000000000c650  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+84)

  #07  pc 0000000000281178  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #08  pc 000000000027d4ac  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #09  pc 000000000027fd5c  /data/app/my.app-1/lib/arm64/libflutter.so

  #10  pc 0000000000067784  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)

  #11  pc 000000000001c604  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
```

I tested it on many real devices and many simulators too (x86_x64). Unfortunately (or fortunately) it worked fine on all these tests.

To be honest, I have no idea what to do. If someone have a hint on what is happening or maybe how to reproduce this, I would be very grateful.

**Flutter doctor**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.18362.356], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at C:\Users\Willian\Documents\Repositories\flutter
    • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (7 days ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Willian\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Willian\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

EDIT:

The problem is not the appbundle. I tried with --split-per-abi with two apk's ("armeabi-v7a" and "arm64-v8a") and the problem is still happening.

Comment: This may fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944735/3307072

Answer (score 2):

I faced this kind of freezing problem. Flutter doctor didn't mention any problem. After building app freeze, I used to be flutter master channel. I switch my flutter to stable and build apk it work fine.

Command:

```
flutter channel stable
```

Comment: Yes this is actually true for the beta channel too. but this is the only way to test flutter web at this moment. do you have any other suggestions on the problem?
I checked my windows system monitor and found out that android studio freezes because of flutter.bat
you can check that in your home dir @ .AndroidStudio3.6\system\log

Answer (score 0):

Same for me here for **master** channel:

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.14.7-pre.74, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-US)

Switching to **stable** resolved the issue..